# Automorphism groups of $\mathbf Z$, $\mathbf Z[i]$, $\mathbf Z[\omega]$

Tags: ring-theory, integers, automorphism-group, gaussian-integers, eisenstein-integers

I would like to know the automorphism groups of the rational integers $\mathbf Z$, the Gaussian integers $\mathbf Z[i]$, and the Eisenstein integers $\mathbf Z[\omega]$.

My question is, would $\text{Aut}(R)$ refer to the group of *group automorphisms* or to the group of *ring automorphisms*?

If $\text{Aut($R$)}$ refers to the group of group automorphisms, I would guess
$\text{Aut}(\mathbf Z) = C_2$, $\text{Aut}(\mathbf Z[i]) = C_4$, and $\text{Aut}(\mathbf Z[\omega]) = C_6$.

If $\text{Aut($R$)}$ refers to the group of ring automorphisms, I would guess
$\text{Aut}(\mathbf Z) = C_1$, $\text{Aut}(\mathbf Z[i]) = C_2$, and $\text{Aut}(\mathbf Z[\omega]) = C_2$.

Also, what if I wanted to compute the automorphism group of a field?

Comment: Indeed the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ for given $X$ depends on which structure you are preserving with your automorphisms (and $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbf{Rings}}(R)=\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbf{Fields}}(R)$ if $R$ is a field).  Anyway, your intuition is off in the case of groups -- $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}[i])\cong\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}[\omega])\cong\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}^2)=GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ (automorphisms as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules aka abelian groups).